# how do i make this wget process not run in the background

Tags: wget

Right now my wget is:

```
wget -Ncq -e \"convert-links=off\" --load-cookies /dev/null --tries=50 --timeout=45 --no-check-certificate \"$download\" -O $prefix$title.webm &
```

and it runs in the background, i dont want it to be in the background. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget -Ncq -e \"convert-links=off\" --load-cookies /dev/null --tries=50 --timeout=45 --no-check-certificate \"$download\" -O $prefix$title.webm #&
```

`&` sends to background
`#` is a comment

Comment: ... or you could simply remove the `&`.

Comment: wow i didnt think i was so simple.. thanks for helping a newbie to commands in the terminal!

Comment: @melpomene eventually he will figure it out :-)